# Hadoop: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop

I am following along with this tutorial which is pretty simple(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_mapreduce.htm) and everything runs fine till I try to run the java file.

I get the following stacktrace.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ProcessUnits
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I have tried this a number of different ways and I always get ClassNotFoundException. I get the feeling it has something to do with Hadoop classpath or something. Please help.

Comment: For what it's worth, that's a super old tutorial in terms of Hadoop API usage and not many people actually write pure Java mapreduce code anymore.

Comment: I'm new and just want to get a feel for Hadoop and MapReduce. Can you point to a tutorial?

Comment: I'd probably point to the official examples on the Apache hadoop page...

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class ProcessUnits 
{ 
   //Mapper class 
   public static class E_EMapper extends MapReduceBase implements 
   Mapper<LongWritable ,/*Input key Type */ 
   Text,                /*Input value Type*/ 
   Text,                /*Output key Type*/ 
   IntWritable>        /*Output value Type*/ 
   { 

      //Map function 
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
      OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,   
      Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
      { 
         String line = value.toString(); 
         String lasttoken = null; 
         StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line,"\t"); 
         String year = s.nextToken(); 

         while(s.hasMoreTokens())
            {
               lasttoken=s.nextToken();
            } 
         int avgprice = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken.trim()); 
         output.collect(new Text(year), new IntWritable(avgprice)); 
      } 
   } 


   //Reducer class 
   public static class E_EReduce extends MapReduceBase implements 
   Reducer< Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable > 
   {  

      //Reduce function 
      public void reduce( Text key, Iterator <IntWritable> values, 
         OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
         { 
            int maxavg=30; 
            int val=Integer.MIN_VALUE; 

            while (values.hasNext()) 
            { 
               if((val=values.next().get())>maxavg) 
               { 
                  output.collect(key, new IntWritable(val)); 
               } 
            } 

         } 
   }  
   //Main function 
   public static void main(String args[])throws Exception 
   { 
      JobConf conf = new JobConf(ProcessUnits.class); 
      conf.setJobName("max_eletricityunits"); 
      conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); 
      conf.setMapperClass(E_EMapper.class); 
      conf.setCombinerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
      conf.setReducerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
      conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class); 
      conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class); 

      FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0])); 
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1])); 

      JobClient.runJob(conf); 
   } 
}
```

this code is working fine. `ProcessUnits` is main class,I think, You have changed the name of your main class. `JobConf conf = new JobConf(ProcessUnits.class);` where you have not changed according to your main class. Give the class main in job according to your programs main class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your jar file in your `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` and verify that you wrote a full canonical name of the class `mypackage.MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you are running the command properly (check the current directory and the class name, you should have hadoop.ProcessUnits and not just ProcessUnits, see below).

$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar units.jar hadoop.ProcessUnits input_dir output_dir

If it still does not work try the below command

$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar units.jar -cp ./* hadoop.ProcessUnits input_dir output_dir

Answer (score -1):

This also occurs if there is an error in the process of building the jar file that is going to be used as an argument to "hadoop jar". That can result in the Main-class in the jar file manifest being "null" instead of null. That will prevent the hadoop jar command from getting the main class from the command line arguments.